# Did receive memory warning when alloc UIButton and UILabel

Tags: ios, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting, didreceivememorywarning

This is the situation:
I've a `UIScrollView` (called `A`) that scrolls horizontally. For this scroll view the property `pagingEnabled` is setted to `YES`. On the right of the screen I've a `UIButton`, that's attached to `self.view` and doesn't scroll with scroll view.

[image]

When tapped, this button shows a `UIView` with another `UIScrollView` (called `B`) inside that scrolls vertically. This scroll view contains a list of `UIButton` and `UILabel`. Every `UIButton` as an `UIImage` as backgroundImage. I used `UIButton` instead `UIImageView` because in this way is easy to manage the touch event on the image. The `UILabel` contains a description for every image.

[image]

The problem:
For every page in `A scroll view`, I need to change the `UIButton` contained in the `B scroll view`, because every page has a different image list. So, in the `scrollView:didEndScrollingAnimation` scroll view delegate method I remove the old `UIButton` and the old `UILabel` from the view and I remove also from the `NSArray` in which they're contained.
The I create a new list of `UIButton` and `UILabel`, I add to `self.view` and insert in the array, with `[array addObject:]`.

After a variable number of scroll the app receive a **memory warning message** and the will killed from the system.

I use ARC, so is almost impossible to understand if the old object are deallecated (and in any case would be very difficult because they are system objects).

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have any other expensive operations happening in your app?  The only thing here that would really cause memory pressure are the images.  Have you tried profiling your app?  You should do that and see what is hogging all the memory / not getting released.

Comment: Hey Fry, I got similar kind of problem. Got it solved? If yes, please update this post please.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case, is the same I recommend to others:

- Use profile and analyse the difference between heaps. This way you are able to check the memory footprint of your application between each swipe.

For a basic tutorial of how to do it, you can check [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html). I know this is a bit vague and you would want a objective answer, but the thing is that, what you think is that the problem right now, might not correspond to the real issue in your application. If you need further help after analysing your heap, just edit your question and let us know.

And [this](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) is the original article I used, from [Mr. bbum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum).